# SQL query suddenly runs slowly until base table's stats are gathered

Tags: oracle, select, statistics

We have a scheduled job that loads table A from multiple tables twice a day. During that procedure, there is a one separate single select statement that gets two columns from table B. That is:

```
select column1, column2 
into l_col1, l_col2
from Table B
where ....
```

The job starts, goes through several selects in a procedure, and when it comes to the above select it halts, in a session window we see that above select is holding the session and when we gather stats for that Table B, it solves the problem, the query runs fast in seconds.

However, this problem appears again when the job runs for the second time in a day. The same thing happens even though Table B has not changed, no transactions have been made to it. We gather statistics again to fasten the query. We tried to add a job to gather stats for it before the main job starts but it did not help. Anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Gathering stats is probably invalidating a cursor and the associated execution plan, and so forces the DB to compute a new one, which is better. Does this query use bind variables? Is it used by different procedures (with different values for these variables)?

Comment: @gsalem, no it doesn't use bind variables, the query itself is inside a function that receives several parameters which are used in where clause of the query. Is there any way to force db to compute a new plan every time it executes this query? Maybe there is a some hint that i can use?

Comment: @Sherzodbek - the optimiser will still treat the parameters as bind variables when it parses the query. If you look in `v$sql` you'll see the PL/SQL parameter/variable names replaces with `:B0` etc.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for clarification, these parameters i.e bind variables are created and assigned values from each row from Table A in main procedure that calls the function.

Comment: If you know what's the good plan, you can fix it by using sql_profiles (google it to see how to do that). You can also add hints to influence the plan. It depends a lot on the difference between the 2 plans, also depends on your init params.